# Advice on Gather

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a better way to write this gather? I have a list of particles, "particlelist",  and a list of particle coordinates, "coordlist" and I want to put all the particles into a 3-dimensional ng x ng x ng array of cubic boxes of width d. Each coordinate takes values between xmin and xmin + d x ng. boxIndx contains the correct box for any particle given the particle coordinates. I can then place the appropriate particle into its proper box.

The code below is easy to read but it is a little slow. I know that AppendTo's are supposed to be no-no's but replacing it with Reap and Sow results in even slower times. The test problem typically takes .13-.17 on my Mac laptop.  Thanks.

```
BoxEmUp3[coordlist_, particlelist_, ng_, d_, xmin_] :=
    Module[{ParticleListByBox,particleIndx, boxIndx},

  ParticleListByBox = ConstantArray[{}, ng^3];
  Do[
   boxIndx = 1 + Floor[(coordlist[[particleIndx, 1 ;; 3]] - xmin)/d].{1, ng, ng^2};

   AppendTo[ParticleListByBox[[boxIndx]], particlelist[[particleIndx]]];,

   {particleIndx, Length[particlelist]}];
  Return[ParticleListByBox];]

xyztst = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10^6, 3}];
free = RandomSample[Range[10^6], 10^4];
BoxEmUp3[xyztst[[free]], free, 20, 1., -10] // Timing
```

Comment: take a look at `BinLists[]`

Comment: It looks to me that BinLists will place the particle coordinates into Boxes but not the particle indexes? I want to store the indexes, not the coordinates.

Comment: I had hoped I could use Gather[] for this but I want the empty boxes. A vanilla application of Gather only returns the boxes that have particles in them. I don't know if there is some way to trick Gather into returning the empty ones as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although not so faster than yours, yet try next :

```
NewBoxEmUp3[coordlist_, particlelist_, ng_, d_, xmin_] := 
   Module[{ParticleListByBox, particleIndx, boxIndx, temp},
   ParticleListByBox = ConstantArray[{}, ng^3];
   boxIndx = {1, ng, ng^2}.# & /@ Quotient[coordlist - xmin, d] + 1;
   temp = MapThread[List, {boxIndx, particlelist} ];
   particleIndx = {#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[temp, First];
   (ParticleListByBox[[First@#]] = Last@#) & /@ particleIndx;
   ParticleListByBox]

 xyztst = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10^6, 3}];
 free = RandomSample[Range[10^6], 10^4];

 ans1 = BoxEmUp3[xyztst[[free]], free, 20, 1., -10]; // Timing
 ans2 = NewBoxEmUp3[xyztst[[free]], free, 20, 1., -10]; // Timing

 (* {0.109201, Null} *)
 (* {0.031200, Null} *)

 ans1==ans2

 (* True *)
```